# Copy from one word to another VB.net

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKL6l.png)

Basically, I just want to be able to start a copy from one specific string, to another. So no matter what is in between  and , I want it to be able to be copied to the clipboard. I have tried many different operations and I cannot find a single answer anywhere. Please someone help?

Comment: Your description of the problem is very poor. Try again to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation. Also, you say that you have tried many things but you have shown us nothing. Show us your best attempt. For one thing, that proves that you've tried, which anyone can claim without having done so. Secondly, if we can see the code then that might overcome your poor explanation to some degree. Thirdly, if we can see what you're thinking then we may be able to correct that thinking and help avoid similar mistakes in future. Teach a man to fish.

Comment: Sorry, So this is what i have,

I am gather text from and HTML code that is generated differently every search.

Example:
"</skillAT>43,193</skillAT>"
Obviously, the number is going to be the difference the next time.

i'm trying to copy the "43,193" within that string and leave out the rest of the non-sense and turn the number into a integer.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is vague, broad, shows little effort, doesnt ask a programming question and several other things that make it off topic (which is the reason for the down votes and close votes).  If you want a good answer, you have to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

if its a number you could for loop all the characters and parse each of the chars into an integer, any that will can then be added to another string variable and then parsed into an integer.

```
    Dim string_thathasvalue As String = "</skillAT>49000</skillAT>"
    Dim intvalue As Integer
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To string_thathasvalue.Count - 1

        If Integer.TryParse(string_thathasvalue.Substring(i, 1), intvalue) Then
            sb.Append(string_thathasvalue.Substring(i, 1))
        End If

    Next

    intvalue = Integer.Parse(sb.ToString)
```

or if its a string between the text then find the index of `">"` and the index of `"</"` and then substring it. like so:-

```
Sub Main()
    Dim string_thathasvalue As String = "</skillAT>DEMDOMLOLIPOP90G</skillAT>"
    Dim first_index As Integer
    Dim second_index As Integer
    Dim newstring As String = ""
    For i = 0 To string_thathasvalue.Count - 1
        If string_thathasvalue.Substring(i, 1) = ">" Then
            first_index = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For i = string_thathasvalue.Length - 2 To 0 - 1 Step -1

        If string_thathasvalue.Substring(i, 2) = "</" Then
            second_index = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim lengthofword As Integer = Math.Abs((first_index - second_index))
    newstring = string_thathasvalue.Substring(first_index, lengthofword)

    Console.WriteLine(newstring)
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```